# html5 date input empty on iphone and android after vue mounts

Tags: vue.js

Ok groovers... We have an html5 date input in a server rendered page, to which we have added Vue. On iphone and android, on one screen, the value disappears from view when Vue mounts. On chrome desktop, no problem. Inspecting with devtools, the value attribute is still present and correctly set. Nothing, to my eyes, has changed, but the value is not visible.

**before**
[image]
 **after**
[image]

What the heck?

Comment: Could you add some code? Are you using a string or date object to display the data?

Comment: The value is set by the server. Here is the string copied from Sources tab... `<input type="date" id="INP_DATE_IMPUT" name="INP_DATE_IMPUT" size="7" onchange="OnChangeDate(this);" value="2017-10-27">`